# required field validator

Tags: asp.net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

Hi I used required field valiator.

now if I disable javascript. I can submit the form, why? No serverside validation?

I have set the validaton group of the submit button and the validator..

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you checking `Page.IsValid` within the submit button's serverside `Click` event?

Comment: Hmm no. But I thought I get the same error message, even after the postback?... is this not possible? how to do that?

Comment: If Page.IsValid then ... else...end if

Comment: you are right, its auto visible, if it goes to else, thank you really!